# Django 1.8 App shows folder strucutre when added SSL

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, ssl

My site is working on http

I now want it to work using a SSl certificate. I've generated the keys and set up the virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIDaemonProcess pms python-path=/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp:/home/ubuntu/myapp/env/lib/python3.4$
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ServerAdmin support@myapp.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key

    ServerName leanhotelsystem.com
    ServerAlias *.leanhotelsystem.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin support@myapp.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I've also set in wsgi.py:

```
os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
```

and in settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

The problem is that when i access the url with https it shows my folder structure, instead of rendering the homepage.
If I access via http it works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forget your WSGI settings section in your new VirtualHost.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I thought I only needed to set that up in one of the hosts. For anyone else that might need this, I copied the `WSGIProcessGroup` and `WSGIScriptAlias` settings, but not the `WSGIDaemonProcess` (because as far as I am aware, you can't have the 2 daemons running)